# Mirror-networking in Unity. OnServerSceneChanged doesn't get called after scene change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

In my game I change the scene to a game scene with an overriden ServerChangeScene(). This is done in NetworkManagerLobby.cs
**NetworkManagerLobby.cs:**

```
public void StartTransitionScene() //sets scene to loading scene
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().path == menuScene)
        {
            if (!IsReadyToStart()) { return; }

            ServerChangeScene("Game");
        }
    }

public override void ServerChangeScene(string newSceneName)
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().path == menuScene && newSceneName.Contains("Game"))
        {
            for (int i = RoomPlayers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) //converts room players to game players
            {
                var conn = RoomPlayers[i].connectionToClient;
                var gameplayerInstance = Instantiate(gamePlayerPrefab);
                gameplayerInstance.SetDisplayName(RoomPlayers[i].DisplayName);

                NetworkServer.Destroy(conn.identity.gameObject);

                NetworkServer.ReplacePlayerForConnection(conn, gameplayerInstance.gameObject);
            }
        }
        base.ServerChangeScene(newSceneName);
    }

public override void OnServerSceneChanged(string sceneName)
    {
        if(sceneName.Contains("Game"))
        {
            GameObject playerSpawnSystemInstance = Instantiate(playerSpawnSystem);
            NetworkServer.Spawn(playerSpawnSystemInstance);
        }

    }
```

The scene then transitions to Game scene(NetworkManager is not destroyed and is present in the scene), but the OnServerSceneChanged callback is not being called. Hence why the players are not spawning on spawnpoints in the scene.
[scene photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFhsw.png)

I isolated the problem to this function, as I thought it was the spawn system itself that was the problem. The function was not called on a debug.

Comment: im a little confused.   surely base change scene should be called before adding things to the scene not after? as nothing in the code actually seems to load a new scene

Comment: We convert the lobby players to game players and then change the scene.

Comment: @BugFinder I tried to place base first, this way the game didn't load in the game players.